# Getting 404 when using Spring Security in Spring Boot application when accessing API

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I want to protect some of the API(s) using JWT token and I am following https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/tree/5.3.3.RELEASE/samples/boot/oauth2resourceserver link to implement a resource server which will validate the JWT token coming as part of Authorization header.

I have below dependencies in my pom

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
         <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
         <version>5.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the securityConfiguration class.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(2)
public class OAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri}")
String jwkSetUri;

@Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
String jwkIssuerUri;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
            {
                try {
                    authorizeRequests
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/message/**").authenticated();
                       
                        // .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/message/**").authenticated();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        )
        .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
    // @formatter:on
}

OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator() {
    return new JwtClaimValidator<List<String>>("aud", aud -> aud.contains("something"));
}

@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder) JwtDecoders.fromIssuerLocation(this.jwkIssuerUri);
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = audienceValidator();
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(this.jwkIssuerUri);
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);
    jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(this.jwkSetUri).build();
}

}
```

Here is my application.properties

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/************/discovery/v2.0/keys
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://login.microsoftonline.com/***************/v2.0
```

My API(s) for testing purpose

```
@GetMapping("/message")
    public String message(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt) {
        return "secret message" + " " + jwt.getIssuerUri();
    }

    @PostMapping("/message")
    public String createMessage(@RequestBody String message) {
        return String.format("Message was created. Content: %s", message);
    }
```

Now, when I calling http://localhost:8080/message without sending any authorization header it throws HTTP 401. However, when I create a valid token and send that token as part of "Authorization" header as Bearer token the application throw HTTP status 404

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-18T00:32:18.320+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/message"
}
```

While debugging the code during startup I notices that below line return an object with an Oauth2Error attribute populated which says "invalid_request: aud is not a valid claim"

```
OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator() {
        return new JwtClaimValidator<List<String>>("aud", aud -> aud.contains("something"));
    }
```

I have even tried commenting this and running the application but I still get 404 Error when Authorization header is present. What might be wrong with my setup?

Comment: Make sure you do not have defined any *context-path* and *request mapping at the class level* and the controller is consists of `@RestController` and it is scanned by spring

Comment: @PatelRomil - Yes, My code does have RestController annotation

Comment: @PatelRomil - Looks like there was some issue with new test API(s) which I had introduced. it is actually working now